# How to enable GZip compression in a self-hosted RESTful WCF webservice?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, compression, wcf-rest

I have a RESTful WCF web service written in C# using .NET 4.0, and I'd like the responses to be compressed using GZip or deflate. (I might need to support compression for requests too, but that is not yet a requirement). It will be deployed as a windows service, i.e. self-hosted WCF service, as IIS hosting is not an option.

My searches have so far come up short. Most hits are either for turning on compression in IIS or writing a custom message encoder for a SOAP based service, neither or which fit my scenario.

If you have any pointers for how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You really need to go for the custom encoder route (sample with code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx) if you want to do GZip compression in a self-hosted scenario (on 4.5 it looks like there is support for compression on the binary encoding, per the announcement at the [MSDN WCF Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/threads), but it doesn't exist out-of-the-box for 4.0). Why doesn't the custom encoder work for your scenario?

Comment: Thanks for responding right away. I don't know for sure that custom encoder isn't the way to go, but the sample you linked to is a SOAP service, and I wasn't quite sure how to modify it work for a WCF RESTful service. I'll take another look at it.

Comment: You can create an instance of the GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement passing an existing encoding binding element to it - if you pass the WebMessageEncodingBindingElement (which is not used for SOAP), then your endpoint using GZip won't be using SOAP either.